# Checkbox image label Select effect only applying on hover, not when checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have check boxes which I have images set for the labels, and I'm using code which applies an effect when hovered over. However when tested in a fiddle the hover effect stays when selected and doesn't show the actual check tick box, only issue with the fiddle is that this only works on the last checked not all checked.

However when I apply this to my site only the hover effect works, the effect doesn't stay on any selected and the tick boxes stay visible.

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zgh24/1169/

The only differences between that in my code is that the DIV it is in also has classes, I'm using bootstrap.

HTML:

```
<div id="sites" class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="padding:5px">

    <input type="checkbox" name="site" id="so" value="stackoverflow" /><label for="so"><img src="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico" alt="Stack Overflow" /></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="site" id="sf" value="serverfault" /><label for="sf"><img src="http://sstatic.net/serverfault/img/favicon.ico" alt="Server Fault" /></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="site" id="su" value="superuser" /><label for="su"><img src="http://sstatic.net/superuser/img/favicon.ico" alt="Super User" /></label>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.input_hidden {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}

.selected {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#sites label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}


#sites label:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#sites label img {
    padding: 3px;    
}
```

JS:

```
<script>
  $('#sites input:checkbox').addClass('input_hidden');
  $('#sites label').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  });
</script>
```

So my issue is sort of 2, I have a Fiddle which sort of does what I want, and then the fiddle I do have doesn't full work when I implement it.

I'm assuming I possibly have some css which is conflicting with that I'm trying to do, but I don't see how or what.

Any help is very appreciated -Tom

Comment: Even not related to your issue but couldn't you use CSS only: `input[type=checkbox]:checked + label img {
    background-color: #ccc;
}`  http://jsfiddle.net/Zgh24/1170/  Maybe not behaviour you are expecting

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes perfect behaviour, the fiddle I posted was adapted another question on here, but yours seems to do exactly the same and better :) and works as intended on my site!

Comment: @A.Wolff how you did in fiddle without writing jquery or javascript code?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Using CSS pseudo class `:checked` as in my previous comment

Comment: how on label click, checkbox is checked?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad that's the purpose of `for` attribute of label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use only CSS pseudo class `:checked` and targeting next sibling label:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label img
```

Finally, you should use as CSS rules:

```
#sites label:hover img,
#sites input[type=checkbox]:checked + label img {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zgh24/1172/)

FYI, you could wish in some case to use instead of `checkboxes` `radio` buttons as in this jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Zgh24/1173/

That could let you use persistant style on some element using only CSS with radio buttons hiddden:

http://jsfiddle.net/Zgh24/1174/

Answer (score 0):

May be not sure.. the class .selected is used by bootstrap core and that style is applied to your label element.

Use your browser to see what style is applied.